# PHP from repository, upgrade to 5.5

Tags: php, debian, apt, repository, upgrade

On my Debian VPS I have installed PHP 5.4 from debian wheezy repository. Now I would like to upgrade PHP to 5.5, but I would like to still be able to continue upgrades by apt-get. Is it good way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DotDeb](http://www.dotdeb.org/instructions/) provides packages for PHP 5.5 and 5.6 on Debian Wheezy.

Comment: Is it secure to take packages from them?